# Запрет на изменение файлов на определенной ветке (git)

Tags: git, git-branch

Решил устроить репозитарий следующим образом:

Ветки

```
dev
test
master
```

Процесс разработки хочу устроить следующим образом:

```
dev -> test -> master
```

С моей точки зрения, выглядит логичным, если на ветке test запретить изменение файлов (чтобы не мерджить из ветки test в dev, т.е. в обратном направлении).

Можно ли средствами git, или как-то иначе это реализовать? Или лучше решить это другими методами?

Comment: Что значит запретить изменение файлов?

Comment: Это значит, поставить права read-only (Win) или, что аналогично, -r--r--r (Linux)

Comment: ну, поставьте. кто вам мешает?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, дело в том, что, по всей видимости, git не отслеживает права на файлы. После переключения ветки, права не меняются соответственно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207728/4827341 только зачем?

Comment: В таких ситуациях запрещают не изменение файлов, а push в ветку.